# Undefined JSON object, only in IE11

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer

I have the following JSON file that I'm loading into a page.

```
{"crawl":[
    {"class":"1", "info":"info 1"},
    {"class":"2", "info":"info 2"},
    {"class":"3", "info":"info 3"},
    {"class":"4", "info":"info 4"},
    {"class":"5", "info":"info 5"}
]}
```

With this script:

```
var objJSON = function(url, successHandler, errorHandler) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var obj = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    } else {
        var obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    };
    obj.open('get', url, true);
    obj.responseType = 'json';
    obj.onload = function() {
        var status = obj.status;
        if (status == 200) {
            successHandler && successHandler(obj.response);
        } else {
            errorHandler && errorHandler(status);
        }
    };
    obj.send();
};
objJSON('crawl.json', function(data) {
    crawlArray = data.crawl;
    console.log(crawlArray);
});
```

In Firefox, this outputs the correct array of objects. IE 11 claims the array is undefined. Additionally, in the full script, where I'm iterating through the array, the IE11 console also says `Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference.` Any help here would be great. I hope I'm just missing something simple.

Comment: Did you try changing the url to '/crawl.json' ?

Comment: Which line generates this error ?

Comment: could you put the output of data

Comment: @chriswirz, yes... even with the path change, it is still undefined
@wawawoom I believe `crawlArray = data.crawl`
@ÁlvaroTouzón the output of `data` returns the JSON contents.

Comment: If the output of data returns the JSON contents, crawlArray = eval(data); crawlArray = crawlArray['crawl'];